# Full brightness when plugging in the laptop charger on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, laptop, brightness, charging

I have Kubuntu 19.10 (Plasmashell 5.16.5) on a laptop. When I plug in the charger, it goes to full brightness.

How can I change this behaviour so that it retains the same brightness, and I don't get a spotlight in my face every time?

Comment: Or maybe one could uncheck the "Screen brightness" box in both tabs?

Comment: I just checked, "Screen brightness" is unchecked in both tabs, and the level is the same in both. I'll try turning them on and seeing if it has any effect.